Binomial (link = logit) GAM model question
I'm working on a Generalized Additive Model with a binomial logit-linked distribution and have become a bit stuck on some things and haven't been able to reconcile. I've read through the help document, online posts (stacked overflow and cross validated), and even lifted the hood on mgcv (and other packages) to gain some insight but have come up short. I put together a reproducible example and the same issues persist so it's not "just my data".
library(mgcv)
set.seed(1)
x <- 1:100
y_binom <- cbind(rpois(100, 5 + x/2), rpois(100, 100))
prop.val <- (y_binom[,1]/y_binom[,2])

gam_m <- gam(y_binom ~ x, family =  binomial(link = "logit"))
pred <- predict(gam_m,data.frame(x = seq(1,100,0.5)),type = "response",se=T)

crit.t <- qt(0.025, df.residual(gam_m), lower.tail = FALSE)
pred.fit <- pred$fit
UCI <- pred.fit+(crit.t*pred$se.fit)
LCI <- pred.fit-(crit.t*pred$se.fit)


Something I noticed in plotting observed data and the fitted line. The predicted line (as type="response") seems to sit lower than the observed data. It seems like the model frame Y variable is adjusted using weights (despite not specifying weights). Here is a quick plot of the observed (empty circles) and predicted line (dashed line). When plotting the observed data it makes it look like the model is a really poor fit (granted I haven't looked at model fit in this example).

plot(prop.val~x,cex = 1.25,lwd=0.1,
     xlab = "X Value",
     ylab = "Proportion")
lines(pred.fit ~ seq(1,100,0.5), lty=1,lwd=2);
lines(UCI~seq(1,100,0.5),lty=2);lines(LCI~seq(1,100,0.5),lty=2)


If we add the model frame data (gam_m$y) its obvious (at least to me) that the line is fit to this data. Is the gam_m$yadjust observed data using model weights? If you look at gam_m$weights, you can see it is not constant.
plot(prop.val~x,cex = 1.25,lwd=0.1,
     xlab = "X Value",
     ylab = "Proportion")
points(gam_m$y~x,pch=21,bg=adjustcolor("dodgerblue1",0.5),cex = 1.25,lwd=0.1)
lines(pred.fit ~ seq(1,100,0.5), lty=1,lwd=2);
lines(UCI~seq(1,100,0.5),lty=2);lines(LCI~seq(1,100,0.5),lty=2)
legend("topleft",legend = c("observed$y","model$y","Predicted \u00B1 95% CI"),
       pch=c(21,21,NA),pt.bg=c('white',adjustcolor("dodgerblue1",0.5)),
       lty=c(0,0,1),lwd=c(0.1,0.1,2),
       pt.cex=1.5,bty="n")



Is there a way to inter-relate the prop.val, gam_m$y, and pred? Should they be inter-related? Should I be plotting the "raw" data (i.e. prop.val) or the weighted values (i.e. gam_m$y)?

Here is how the observed and weighted adjusted values relate. So it seems like the logit back-transformation (or some kind of transformation) is needed.
plot(gam_m$y~prop.val,
     xlab = "Data $ Y",
     ylab = "Model $ Y");
abline(0,1,lty=2)


Apologies for the relatively basic question, it's a new adventure for me dipping into the binomial logit-linked distributions.

You are either computing prop.val incorrectly or you are incorrectly specifying the model.
In a glm() with family = binomial() you can specify the model as a two-column matrix where the first column is number of successes and the second column the number of failures.
If we assume that y_binom contains columns as per above, i.e. you specified the model correctly, then prop.val is incorrectly computed and instead should be
prop.val <- y_binom[,1] / rowSums(y_binom)

If, however, y_binom[,2] contains the total count per sample, and hence prop.val was computed correctly, then the model is incorrectly specified because y_binom[,2] should be the number of failures but instead you are passing the total count (size) as the second column of the response.
Fix either of these and the fitted line goes close to the data (and in fact, you are already seeing that something is wrong because the data you plotted prop.val is not what is stored in the model as the response).
As it is ambiguous what is in y_binom (you should be explicit as to what you compute in scripts/examples and include comments so what you are trying to do is clear) I won't provide an actual example. Clarify what you intended to be in the columns of y_binom and I will provide further code if your query remains.

I knew I was missing something so simple!! Thanks for the clarification ... and its all making sense now. In the example above (and my data analysis) I was assuming the y_binom[,2] was the total number, therefore the model was incorrectly specified.
